# sort a list of dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sorting

I just want to sort by first_name this list in python

```
list = [ { "profile" :  { "first_name" : "a", "last_name" : "b" } } ,
         { "profile" :  { "first_name" : "c", "last_name" : "d" } } ,
         { "profile" :  { "first_name" : "e", "last_name" : "f" } } ]
```

Comment: best not to use `list` as a variable name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To sort the list itself, use:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x['profile']['first_name'])
```

To keep `lst` unsorted and return a sorted list use:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x['profile']['first_name'])
```

Comment: @AtulMakwana - You many have used `.sort()` syntax instead of `sorted()`

Answer (score 9):

This should do it:

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x['profile']['first_name'])
```